C++ doesn't seem to perform math after inputting
I'm trying to write a program that will give me the total of: the subtotal of a product multiplied by .19 (gratuity) plus the subtotal.
I would enter the subtotal amount on the console and it would spit out the total.
This is what I came up with:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int total;    
    int x;
    
    std::cout << "what's the sub?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    total = (.19 * x) + x;
    std::cout << "total is" << total;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}

As I'm sure you're not surprised, when I input the subtotal, I just get x back. For example, for a subtotal inputted of 5, the result on the console is 5. The char c stuff at the end is so the program doesn't end when I hit Enter after I input the subtotal.
I think maybe there are too many x's, but other than that, I have no clue.

change type int to double

The problem is the total can be only whole numbers since you used int since 0.19 * 5 is less than 1 the total will still be 5. Try with 6 to see the total increase because of the 0.19 part: https://ideone.com/hyYPFu

Sometimes C++ looks like math, but C++'s rules are somewhat different from the rules of high school math, and the concept of type, int, double etc, is one way they differ. There are many more differences, which is why it is important to learn how C++ really works and not just make assumptions based on prior experience of math. That will lead you astray.

The problem is that you are using an int to receive the subtotal and to calculate the total. int can't hold a decimal value, only a whole integer.
.19 is a double literal, so (.19 * x) promotes the value of x to double, and you end up with (0.19 * 5.0) = 0.95. Then, you are adding x to that result, promoting the value of x again, so you end up with 0.95 + 5.0 = 5.95. And then, you are assigning that result to total, which is an int, thus truncating off the decimal portion, and you end up with total set to 5.
Use float or double instead when you need to do math with decimal values.
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double total;    
    double x;
    
    std::cout << "what's the sub? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    total = (.19 * x) + x;
    std::cout << "total is " << total;

    std::cin.get();
}


Thank you thank you thank you; I'm slapping my forehead right now because I forgot about int always being a whole number.

You can change the data type of total to float or double. Then, it will display the floating point values obtained and not round them off.

As the other answers say, you explicitly chose to use whole numbers (int is short for "integer"), so the fractional part was immediately discarded.
However, neither float nor double are really correct for currency, because you need an integer number of pennies (or cents) displayed as euros, dollars, pounds or whatever.
Using floating-point will let you calculate and display fractions of a penny when it doesn't make sense.
The correct solution is probably
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

int main()
{
    double sub;    
    
    std::cout << "subtotal? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> sub;

    int pennies = 100 * sub; // this rounds down (truncates)
    int total = 1.19 * pennies;

    std::cout
      << "total is "
      << std::format("{}.{:02}", total/100, total%100)
      << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
}

or we can just convert back to double for printing
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double sub;    
    
    std::cout << "subtotal? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> sub;

    int pennies = 100 * sub; // this rounds down (truncates)
    int total = 1.19 * pennies;

    std::cout
      << "total is "
      << std::setprecision(2)
      // 100.0 is a double literal, so this converts back to double for printing
      << total/100.0
      << '\n';

    std::cin.get();
}


Oh wow, didn't even think of currency, but you are technically correct, the best kind. I have to admit, just looking at this for a second, I'm a little lost, but I'll peruse it and take it in. Seems like a very important lesson to learn (programming for currency properly)

@CarolynDockery when dealing with currency, you should never do math using floating-point types, as you risk introducing rounding errors. You should convert currency to whole cents, do normal integer math on that, then convert back to currency to display the result.
